# Generating XML nodes within SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I noticed generating XML with SQL is quite easy. But I'm trying to do some more advanced stuff.

Is it possible to have an XML that would look something like this

```
<Data timedate="2014-02-13">
  <item id="120" name ="firstItem"
    <subitem id="49">My Value</subitem>
    <subitem id="50">My Other Value</subitem>
  </item>

  <item id="121" name ="secondItem"
    <subitem id="51">My 3rd Value</subitem>
    <subitem id="52">My 4th Value</subitem>
  </item>
</Data>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to structure the data to allow rows to create sub rows, or if I need to use server-side code to generate this.

Comment: You can do this via SQL Server, but I'd look hard at doing it outside of the database. Phil Factor said reminded him of a poem: "...And when she was good, she was very, very good,
But when she was bad she was horrid." That's XML in sql server. (See Phil's article here for that specific reference: https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2012/01/05/using-xml-to-pass-lists-as-parameters-in-sql-server/)

Comment: What does your data look like in tables ???